# How to correctly pass Word2Vec vectors as input to an LSTM

Tags: python, lstm, word2vec, matrix

I am trying to build a text classifier using `lstm` which, in its first layer, has weights get by a `Word2Vec`model.

In order to build a `matrix` containing the `indexes` of each word for each sentence, I have tried: (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42064690/using-pre-trained-word2vec-with-lstm-for-word-generation))

```
X_tr_word2vec = np.array(X_tr_word2vec)
y_tr_word2vec = np.array(y_tr_word2vec)

train_x = np.zeros([X_tr_word2vec.shape[0], max_sentence_length], dtype=np.int32)
train_y = np.zeros([y_tr_word2vec.shape[0]], dtype=np.int32)

for i, sentence in enumerate(X_tr_word2vec):
    for j, word in enumerate(sentence[:-1]):
        train_x[i,j] = model_word2vec.wv.vocab[word].index
```

but, when I run the code, I get this error:`KeyError: 'enquiringly'`, what does it mean?
I suppose that it is about a wrong `train_x`dimension.

**Update:**

I have trained `Word2Vec` model before, with the entire training set:

```
model_word2vec = models.Word2Vec(X_tr_word2vec, size=150, window=9)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means your word `'enquiringly'` is not in your word embedding vocabulary `vocab`.

For out-of-vocabulary(OOV) words, there is usually a embedding vector dedicated to them. Try to find that special symbol in the `vocab` and use that corresponding embedding vector.

Comment: I have trained the model before, with the entire training set. Therefore how is it possible that the model doesn't have some words in its vocabulary?